# Is $\min(x+y,z) \leq \min(x,z)+\min(y,z) $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x, y, z > 0$. Is the following true then? $$\min(x+y,z) \leq \min(x,z)+\min(y,z) $$

I can't seem to find the answer on Google but maybe I don't know the name of this property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true, and the property is called [*subadditivity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, and could be proved by considering each case:

$$0<x<y<z$$

$$0<x<z<y$$

$$0<z<x<y$$

$$\textit{etc.}$$

Actually, just these three are enough.  The statement is equivalent exchanging $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The relation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. Now divide it in three cases, and deduce the inequality.

**Case I:** $x+y<z$.

**Case II:** $z\leq \min(x,y)$.

**Case III:** $x+y\geq z$ and $x\leq z \leq y$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $x+y<z$ then $x<z$ and $y<z$.
Can you see how to approach the other cases?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in cases and note the trivial: $\min(a,b) \le a$ and $\min(a,b) \le b$

If both $x \le z$ and $y\le z$ than $\min(x+y, z) \le x+ y = \min(x,z)+  \min(y,z)$.

If $x > z$ then  $\min(x+y,z) \le z = \min(x,z) < \min(x,z)+\min(y,z)$.

If $y > z$ then $\min(x+y,z) \le z=\min(y,z) < \min(x,z) + \min(y,z)$.

That's it.